# Sorting a column by another column

Tags: excel, sorting

I have an excel sorting problem. I have a column that contains Names (column A), and a column that contains the Profit (column H). I want column I to contain the names from column A, but sorted by the  ascending/descending order of column H.

I want it to look like this:

```
A------------------------B---C---D--E----F-------G-------H----------I----------------

Name-----------------""---""- -""--""---""-------""--------Profit---""---------------   

Fruit Salad----------3---0---0---3---108----828----720------Fruit Salad

Cookies--------------0---2---0---3---126----902----776------Shortcake 

Korean Kimchi----6---0---0---2---144----970----826------Cookies 

Shortcake-----------0---3---0---2---144----904----760------Fried Chicken 

Fried Chicken-----0---3---0---3---162----964----802------Korean Kimchi
```

I started fooling around but then I got an interest in this.

Comment: Normally, you would sort the entire set, such that each row would be rearranged with the sort.  Do you have a need to preserve the original sort order of the data?

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula in column I (starting with I1):

```
=INDEX($A$1:$A$7,MATCH(LARGE($H$1:$H$7,ROW(I1)),$H$1:$H$7,0))
```

The LARGE function finds the n-th largest, where n is the number of the row where the function is. (So it finds the first largest value for row 1, the 2nd largest for row 2 etc.).

Then we need to find the position for that number in the number list, this is what the match does.

Then an index gets the value from the same row in column A.

Easy :)

Note that this only works as long as you don't have duplicate values in column H.

Comment: Or you could copy the two necessary columns to another location, sort them, then copy them back. But that is boring.